# IronPython, passing a reference to a Byte

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have a C# function i'm trying to call from IronPython. It's defined as...

```
public status extern int OpenNetPort(int Port, string IPaddr, ref byte ComAddr, ref int PortHandle)
```

I do the following...

```
clrType = Type.GetType('System.Byte')

d = 0
comAdr = clr.Reference[Byte](clr.Convert(d, clrType))
rfidHandle = StaticClassReaderB.OpenNetPort(27011, '192.168.0.250', comAdr, 27011)

I get the following when running...
TypeError: expected Byte, got StrongBox[Byte]
```

I've been trying to work around it for days but can't get anything to work.
Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like a C# function to me. More like C++.

Comment: Well that is how it's defined in the document I got from the company in China. If I look at the function in Visual Studio it shows up as...
public status extern int OpenNetPort(int Port, string IPaddr, ref byte ComAddr, ref int PortHandle)

Comment: Well *that* looks like C#. All your LPSTR, unsigned char parameters is not C#. I'm not sure why you posted the definition one way in the question and then a different way in your comment.

Comment: Fixed, sorry I was going off the reference doc instead of what was coming out of the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second `ref` argument of your invocation is wrong. For whatever reason IronPython message is misleading.

The c# prototype is still a bit unclear and may hide further surprises. To find out definitive signature of method you can use `ildasm`

Complete example with additional assumptions I made:

c#

```
namespace callingdotnet {
    public class Callingdotnet {
        public static int OpenNetPort(int Port, string IPaddr, ref byte ComAddr, ref int PortHandle) {
            Console.WriteLine("port: " + Port);
            Console.WriteLine("IPaddre: " + IPaddr);
            Console.WriteLine("ComAddr: " + ComAddr);
            Console.WriteLine("PortHandle: " + PortHandle);
            ComAddr = 42;
            PortHandle = 0xdead;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

ironpython:

```
import System
import clr

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"bin\debug\callingdotnet.dll")
import callingdotnet

d = 123
comAddr = clr.Reference[System.Byte](d)
p = 423564
PortHandle = clr.Reference[System.Int32](p)

ret = callingdotnet.Callingdotnet.OpenNetPort(27011, '192.168.0.250', comAddr, PortHandle)
print "-"*40
print "ret = ", ret
print "comAddr: ", comAddr.Value
print "PortHandle: %x" % PortHandle.Value
```

output:

```
$ ~/github/IronLanguages/bin/Debug/ipy.exe -S example-byte-ref.py
port: 27011
IPaddre: 192.168.0.250
ComAddr: 123
PortHandle: 423564
----------------------------------------
ret =  0
comAddr:  42
PortHandle: dead
```

Comment: Thank you! You were correct in that the 2nd reference argument was what was causing the problem and that the error message was misleading. Thanks so much Pawel!